# How does one load RaphaelJS with JSPM?

Tags: javascript, raphael, jspm, systemjs

What's the best way to load RaphaelJS with JSPM? It appears to export things in such a way that the normal

```
jspm install raphael
```

with

```js
import Raphael from 'raphael';
```

does not work.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Multiple defines for anonymous module
```

What's the correct way to install and import RaphaelJS with JSPM/SystemJS?

Answer (score 2):

So far, this appears to be the only solution:

From the command line:

```
jspm install raphael@master
```

In your source:

```js
import 'raphael/dev/eve';
import 'raphael/dev/raphael.core';
import 'raphael/dev/raphael.svg';
import 'raphael/dev/raphael.vml';
import Raphael from 'raphael/dev/raphael.amd';

var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);
var circle = paper.circle(50, 40, 10);
```

Essentially, we pull from the latest source in github on the master branch. However, even that still had issues with some module paths, so I chose to manually import all the dependencies in order. After that, it seems pretty happy.

The first 4 lines of imports should be placed somewhere in your application's bootstrapping. The last line to actually import `Raphael` should be placed in a module local to where you want to actually use `Raphael`.